# Redirect to site page from company website

Tags: force.com-sites, site.com, website-integration

Customer submit online application through our company website and at the end of the process users are redirected to a site page

https://sandboxName-companyname.cs96.force.com/WebsiteAccess/DecisionModule?accountId=0010G11111uURy6QAG

Currently front end team is experiencing "too_many_redirects" error when they make a redirect to the given URL. I tried enough but I am not sure how can the issue be resolved. Any thoughts what could be the issue?

Comment: you could connect your application form instead of on your company site but to your Salesforce Site public page

Comment: I am not sure I could follow you..